# Aptitude aborts automatically after running resolver

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, aptitude

I'm having some issues with aptitude. I'm attempting to install all the fonts available in the debian repos, but apt-get doesn't seem to like the command `apt-get install ttf*` (its conflict resolver can't cope), and I've never been able to get regex expressions and wildcards to work in aptitude. I tried the alternative

```
aptitude search ttf | awk '{print $2}' | xargs aptitude install
```

After running the resolver, it proposes a solution with the standard `Accept this solution? [y/n/q/?]`, but automatically aborts before I have the chance to select an option. I've tried it on 4 different computers, all running the latest version of debian testing, and they all behave exactly the same.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? I can install them one at a time, but I'm sure there are richer things in life...

Comment: Maybe try installing ttf-* (ttf* will include some utilities)

Comment: That doesn't appear to make a difference - apt-get complains it cannot resolve my dependencies, and aptitude still proposes a solution, but immediately aborts before I can respond to it...

Comment: Funny, on my ubuntu there are no complains, just 226 packages to install. Maybe time to look at the complains and figure out what's so wrong it cannot be resolved.

Comment: You are getting the immediate exit because `aptitude` is reading the `y/n/q` response from its input pipe, which has been emptied by `xargs`. Try `... aptitude -y install` to pre-answer the prompt. Or use `... echo xargs aptitude install`, then copy/paste the output (adding quotes if necessary).

Comment: @AFH that's exactly what was happening, thanks! If you post it as an answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the immediate exit because `aptitude` is reading the `y/n/q` response from its input pipe, which has been emptied by `xargs`.

There are two things to try - you can pre-answer the prompt with:

```
aptitude search ttf | awk '{print $2}' | aptitude -y install
```

Or you can display the command which would be executed, then copy/paste the output (adding quotes if necessary, though I doubt they will be) with:

```
aptitude search ttf | awk '{print $2}' | xargs echo aptitude install
```